# Application is crashing when i click settings option in live wallpaper

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper

Nothing is posted in logcat.Application just stops working.
Here is my code form manifest

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <service android:name =".LiveWallpaperAndroid"
     android:label = "@string/app_name"
     android:icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:permission = "android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name ="android.service.wallpaper"
         android:resource ="@xml/livewallpaper" />
    </service>

    <activity android:label="@string/livewallpaper_settings"
        android:name=".LiveWallpaperSettings"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.WallpaperSettings"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Below is my settings Activity code

```
public class LiveWallpaperSettings extends PreferenceActivity
implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
super.onCreate(icicle);
        getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(LiveWallpaperScreen.SHARED_PREFS_NAME);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.football);
getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()
        .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

My xml file for settings is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:title="@string/livewallpaper_settings"
android:key="livewallpaper_settings">

<ListPreference
    android:key="livewallpaper_testpattern"
    android:title="@string/livewallpaper_settings_title"
    android:summary="@string/livewallpaper_settings_summary"
    android:entries="@array/livewallpaper_testpattern_names"
    android:entryValues="@array/livewallpaper_testpattern_prefix"/>
<CheckBoxPreference android:key="livewallpaper_movement"
    android:summary="@string/livewallpaper_movement_summary"
    android:title="@string/livewallpaper_movement_title"
    android:summaryOn="Moving test pattern"
    android:summaryOff="Still test pattern"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

What is wrong here.I am unable to come up with anything because nothing is shown in logcat about any error.

Comment: can you post your whole code .....

Answer (score 0):

it occur many time with me also, i know this problem and solution well,i think you just forgot to change your package name in you xml folder wallpaper.xml file, just check following you got your answeres.

i think you wallpaper.xml // you understand your file name whatever you take

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <wallpaper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:settingsActivity="YourAllPAckageName.YourSettingActivity"
   android:thumbnail="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

like,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <wallpaper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:settingsActivity="com.wallpaperexample.WallpaperSettingsActiity"
   android:thumbnail="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```