# unfortunately live wallpaper picker has stopped on clicking settings in my live wallpaper

Tags: android, libgdx, live-wallpaper

I created a live wallpaper using libgdx.I added an option for settings screen but when i click on settings i get "unfortunately live wallpaper picker has stopped" error.No error is shown in logcat.Here is my code

```
public class LiveWallpaperSettings extends AndroidApplication
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

everything else appears to be normal in this class.Why is this error occuring.

Normally the code for settings incaseof live wallpapers is

```
public class CubeWallpaper2Settings extends PreferenceActivity
implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
```

Can this be a problem.

Comment: Without a logcat we can not tell very much about the error.

Comment: i giving this answers in **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103181/application-is-crashing-when-i-click-settings-option-in-live-wallpaper/25742229#25742229**